# If statement after rand() in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, random, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm a beginner in Objective-C and also in the C language.

My code looks like:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    int randomproces = rand() % 3;
    switch (randomproces) {
        case 0:
            //do this
            break;
        case 1:
            //do this
            break;
        case 2:
            //do this
            break;
        default;
            break;
    }
}
```

Now I want to set something to another 3 buttons to make them correct or incorrect depending on a random situation.

```
- (IBAction)b1:(id)sender {
    //if case 0 then set it correct
    //else incorrect
}

- (IBAction)b2:(id)sender {
    //if case 1 then set it correct
    //else incorrect
}

// etc
```

How do I do this?

Comment: @Joachim: It's a hard job, editing and only touching the whitespace... Good Job!

Comment: Lets see if I understand you better: You have a total of four buttons, the first selects a random value, and that random value will be used in the handlers for the other buttons?

Comment: Yes thats right! Sorry that I can't edit that code but I really couldn't find an option how to add code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to do different things in the in the handlers for `b1`, `b2` and `b3` depending on a random value selected in the handler for `button`?

I that case the simplest is probably to make the random number variable in `button` global, and use that in the other three button handlers:

```
int randomprocess = -1;

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    randomproces = rand() % 3;
    // Do other stuff if needed
}

- (IBAction)b1:(id)sender {
    if (randomprocess == 0) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}

- (IBAction)b2:(id)sender {
    if (randomprocess == 1) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}

- (IBAction)b3:(id)sender {
    if (randomprocess == 2) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I;m sorry you probably haven't understand my question. I know how to use random statement. Now what I need is how to set to another button if statement. LEt me show you an example. You have 5 pictures (picure of dog, cat, elephant, lion and horse). You'll make them show randomly. And you have there 5 button with names of these animals. What I want to do is to set this buttons as correct answers. So if random picute is elephant, set the button with name elephat as correct. Right?

Comment: @user1291672 Okay, see my modified answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't really get it :/
My code looks like:
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
int randomproces = rand() % 3;
    switch (randomproces) {
        case 0: //do this
          break;
        case 1: //do this
          break;
        case 2: //do this
          break;
     default;
     break;

and now I want to set something to another 3 buttons to make them correct or incorrect depending on random situation.

- (IBAction)b1:(id)sender {
      //if case 0 then set it correct
      //else incorrect
- (IBAction)b2:(id)sender {
      //if case 1 then set it correct
      //else incorrect

etc

Comment: @TomasJ So, you have the code like the first version of my answer? What's wrong with it? It do allow you to select from a limited number of random numbers, but so does my modified answer. you simply use `randomprocess` as an index in an array of the thing you want to choose between.

Comment: @TomasJ You seem to keep changing the question you are asking. Instead of putting it in comments, _update your question!_

Comment: That's what I wanted! But still there is a problem. Program don't remember that random value from first button. I made all buttons to write down value of 'randomprocess' and after clicking first button there is really random value and after clicking another buttons it's still -1 or whatever number I declare. And when I try to return that value, it says that the void method can't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the switch statement, thus

```
switch (num)
{
    case 1:
        //do code
        break;

    case 2:
        //more code
        break;

    default:
        //num didn't match any of the cases.
        //process as appropriate
}
```

Some things to note:

- The break at the end of each case is important. If you omit this, the case falls through into the next case. Though this is sometimes intentional, generally it isn't and results in subtle and difficult to understand bugs.
- The 'default' label and code is optional. It is however good programming style to have a default case for exceptional circumstances, as something has probably gone wrong and you should deal with it as such.

Comment: LEt me show you an example. You have 5 pictures (picure of dog, cat, elephant, lion and horse). You'll make them show randomly. And you have there 5 buttons with names of these animals. What I want to do is to set this buttons as correct answers. So if random picute is elephant, set the button with name elephat as correct and other buttons as incorrect. Right?

Comment: That's not an example, that's asking a different question